# Nrf24L01 + Arduino Mega2560 send joystick data

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to send the x and y values of a joystick between two arduino mega 2560 with an nrf24l01. So far I have a transmitter and reciever code but I get wrong values on the reciever.

Transmitter:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7,8);
byte addresses[][6] = {"0x115331","0x222331"};

typedef struct{
  int X;
  int Y;
  int K;
}
Values;

Values v;

void setup() {
pinMode(10, INPUT);
Serial.begin(115200);
radio.begin();
radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
radio.setChannel(108);
radio.setPayloadSize(32);
radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[1]);
radio.openReadingPipe(1,addresses[0]);
}

void loop() {
radio.stopListening();
v.X = analogRead(A0);
v.Y = analogRead(A1);
v.K = digitalRead(10);
Serial.print("X = ");
Serial.println(v.X);
Serial.print("Y = ");
Serial.println(v.Y);
Serial.print("Button status: ");
if (v.K == HIGH)
{
  Serial.println("pressed");
}
else
{
Serial.println("not pressed");
}
radio.write(&v,sizeof(v));
delay(500);
}
```

Reciever:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7,8);
byte addresses[][6] = {"0x115331","0x222331"};

typedef struct{
  int X;
  int Y;
  int K;
}
Values;

Values v;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
radio.begin();
radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[0]);
radio.openReadingPipe(1,addresses[1]);
radio.setChannel(108);
radio.setPayloadSize(32);
radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {
radio.startListening();
if ( radio.available() )
{
  while(radio.available())
  {
    radio.read(&v, sizeof(v));
  }
}
  radio.stopListening();
  Serial.println(v.X);
  Serial.println(v.Y);
  Serial.println(v.K);
delay(1000);
}
```

I'm using the pin configuration from this website: https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-2.4GHz-HowTo

Comment: Provide an example of what you send and what you receive. Anyway, I can suggest you to 1) remove the `if ( radio.available() )` instruction 2) transform the `while(radio.available())` in `while(radio.available() >= sizeof(v))` 3) check if you can call stopListening while reading, or if you shouldn't (after all, the nrf should continue listening)

Comment: I tried the changes you suggested. However I couldn't use while(radio.available() >= sizeof(v)) because radio.available() is a bool. I'm transmitting values between 0 and 1022. But I'm recieving values between 0 and 3847.

Comment: sorry, I thought it was a stream standard interface, instead it looks like it sends and receives packets... try to set the payload size to sizeof(v), but... I don't think it will solve... Maybe try sending some known bytes and match what you receive... Maybe it is just a shift...

Comment: I have tried to send an integer with a constant value of 5000 and I'm recieving different numbers. Mostly something like 256,257,1024,3897 and so on.

Comment: This sounds kind of weird... Sorry, I can't help you more than this... In the past I used the [NRF24 library](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/NRF24/), but apparently they renamed it to [RadioHead](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/). If you don't succeed in setting things up, try with another library like this and try to implement the basic examples, then gradually move up to the final implementation...